# Base.save, callbacks and observers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, save, observer-pattern

Let us say that we have the model Champ, with the following attributes, all with default values of nil: winner, lose, coach, awesome, should_watch.

Let's assume that two separate operations are performed: (1) a new record is created and (2) c.the_winner is called on a instance of Champ.

Based on my mock code, and the observer on the model, what values are saved to the DB for these two scenarios?  What I am trying to understand is the principles of how callbacks work within the context of Base.save operation, and if and when the Base.save operation has to be called more than once to commit the changes.

```
class Champ

  def the_winner
    self.winner = 'me'
    self.save
  end

  def the_loser
    self.loser = 'you'
  end

  def the_coach
    self.coach = 'Lt Wiggles'
  end

  def awesome_game(awesome_or_not=false)
    self.awesome = awesome_or_not
  end

  def should_watch_it(should=false)
    self.should_watch = should
  end

end

class ChampObserver

  def after_update(c)
    c.the_loser
  end

  def after_create(c)
    c.the_coach
  end

  def before_create(c)
    c.awesome_game(true)
    c.should_watch_it(true) if c.awesome_game
  end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example, if you called `champ.winner` on a new and unmodified instance of `Champ`, the instance of Champ would be committed to the DB and would look like this in the database:

```
winner: 'me'
awesome: true
should_watch: true
loser: nil
coach: nil
```

The `after_create` callback would be called if it is a new record, and if not, the `after_update` callback would (this is why `loser` would be nil if the instance was new). However, because they just call a setter method on the instance, they will only update the instance and will not commit more changes to the DB.

You could use `update_attribute` in your observer or model methods to commit the change, but unless you actually need to have the record in the database and then update it, it's wasteful. In this example, if you wanted those callbacks to actually set `loser` and `coach` in the database, it'd be more efficient to use `before_save` and `before_create`.

The Rails guides site has a good overview of callbacks [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview), if you haven't read it already.

Comment: ug, yea, should have included scenario where it's created and updated...but your response is helpful!